# wxpython: How do I update my panels text with SetLabel from within an imported script?

Tags: wxpython, panel

I have a wxpython panel with some buttons. One of these buttons executes a python script that controls a piece of equipment in the lab. Within the python script there is while loop that looks like,

```
 ave_number = 5000
 gpibObj.command('FAVN2,'+str(ave_number)) # Number of Averaging
 gpibObj.command('STRT') #Start measurement bData
 time.sleep(0.5) 
 avg = 0
 print "Number of averages to be taken:",ave_number
 while avg < ave_number:
      avg=int(gpibObj.query("NAVG?0"))
      print('Averages done:'+str(avg))
      sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
      time.sleep(0.3)
```

Currently this prints this just tells the script to pause until the number of averages is where it's supposed to be, and prints the current number of averages to the command line. My question is, is there a way with how this is panel is currently set up to pass the variable avg, a variable that is in a while loop, in an imported script in the panel code, to a command like,

self.histstatusTXT.SetLabel(temptxt)

so that I can see it updated in real time on the panel itself.

Just for clarity sake the buttons looks like:

```
self.btn = wx.Button(self.panel,wx.ID_ANY,"Collect SR785 FFT Only",(5,45))
self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.runScript,self.btn)
```

where the function it is executing is

```
def runScript(self, e):
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self.panel,'New Directory Name?',"path-save","",style=wx.OK)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dir = dlg.GetValue()
    dlg.Destroy()
    os.system("mkdir {0}".format(dir))
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self.panel,'Name of Files?',"path-save","",style=wx.OK)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    filename =dlg.GetValue()
    dlg.Destroy()
    x = dir + '/' + filename
    self.sb.SetStatusText('Working')
    temptxt = "Data saved to {0}".format(x)
    self.histstatusTXT.SetLabel("Collecting SR785 Data")
    wx.Yield()
    fft_group_SINGLE_FFT_function.FFT1(x)
    self.sb.SetStatusText('Ready')
    self.histstatusTXT.SetLabel(temptxt)
```

and the function fft_group_SINGLE_FFT_function.FFT1(x) contains the while loop above. Apologies if the problem doesn't make sense. If it doesn't let me know and i can attempt to explain a different way.

Thanks.

Comment: `wx.lib.newevent` or `pubsub` both allow communication between a subprocess and the main process, in an event driven way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Pass the label itself (`self.histstatusTXT`) or a function pointer to (`self.histstatusTXT.SetLabel`), to `fft_group_SINGLE_FFT_function.FFT1()` as an additional (possibly optional, if this function is used elsewhere) argument.
This allows you to set the label text from within the `FFT1` function.

I would pass the function pointer, so the `FFT1` function would not be able to change other attributes of the `hisistatusTXT` label (unless you need to).